# Numpy equilvalent of double-loop

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I would like to do the equivalent of this in numpy:

```
upper_triangle = []
for i in range(len(points)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(points)):
        upper_triangle.append(points[i],points[j])
```

Starting from:

```
r1 = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv, dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True, max_rows=10).reshape(10,1)
print(r1)

[[(46.5850122581, 5.58578294146)]
 [(48.1923697643, 6.72962889202)]
 [(50.3091545259, 3.02186108116)]
 [(49.1339723471, -0.158515066328)]
 [(42.9817651679, 2.01049024009)]
 [(44.3029325431, 5.00596735706)]
 [(43.8825601072, 2.98664718926)]
 [(48.0980144211, 5.14070044621)]
 [(48.8361825401, 2.56443736814)]
 [(43.1412292044, 2.33961454504)]]
```

However, I can't seem to find the relevant commands.

Comment: How about `from itertools import combinations; upper_triangle = list(combinations(points,2))`?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for this; however I was looking for a numpy implementation because my array may contain around 50,000 points so I wanted to find the most efficient way. Would itertools not be slower and use more RAM? If I run the cross using either the loop or the combinations that hits my RAM limit

Comment: Wtih 50K points, you are looking at having an array of shape `(2499950000,4)` many of whose elements are repeated. Do you really need such a huge array? How are you going to use those elements? Can you optimize the relevant algorithm instead that uses this data?

Comment: With 50k I would get a high number (50*49*0.5=1,249,975,000); however I want a list to be able to lambda map or vectorise a distance function

Comment: If you are performing distance calculation, you can directly get those with [`scipy.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) without having to create those combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have an `(n, 2)` array of coordinates, you can use [`np.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

```
i, j = np.triu_indices(points.shape[0], k=1)    # k=1 excludes the main diagonal
upper_triangle = np.hstack((points[i], points[j]))
```

This will give you an `(n*(n-1)/2, 4)` array where each row contains the *x,y* coordinates for rows *i,j* in `points`: `(xi, yi, xj, yj)`.

However, it looks like part of your problem is with parsing the text file - you want an `(n, 2)` float array rather than an `(n, 1)` vector of tuples. Perhaps you need to strip `"("` and `")"` characters?

Comment: Thank you this worked fine for me! The test case of 10 rows gave me 45 combinations as it should

Comment: @Divakar is correct, though - if your goal is just to compute pairwise distances then it will probably be more efficient to use [`scipy.spatial.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) directly on `points`

Comment: Ah so passing this to scipy.pdist and specifying the custom distance function I want (geopy.distances.vincenty) would be quicker than creating this pairwise array and lambda mapping the vincenty distance function on it? I wanted to test the timing differences actually. This is also useful to have because as a first step (trimming the points I don't need) I wanted to use cKDtree (quad-tree)

Comment: If you're using a distance function written in Python then there probably there won't be much difference. `pdist` is much faster if you use one of the built-in distance metrics which are implemented in C.